# conditional parameters in ruby, how to check for nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optional-parameters

Tried the following

```
def pkill(process_name, *host)  
         puts host.nil? # =>  false
         puts host.empty? # =>  true
         puts host # =>  nil
         puts host[0].nil? # => true
    end
```

Now if I call `send("pkill", blah, nil)`, how/why is `host` false??

Pretty new to ruby, so keep it smooth :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's not nil, it's empty array.

```
def pkill(process_name, *host)  
  host.nil? # => false
  host # => []
  host.empty? # => true
end

pkill 'blah'
```

Comment: Then you're doing something else. What ruby are you on? I'm on 1.9.3

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Well, it's pretty old. Can you upgrade?

Comment: so, is that a bug in that build or something?

Comment: I have installed 1.8.7p358 and checked. Result is the same. Try upgrading to this patchlevel.

Comment: I am using it with capistrano, a deployment tool which we use to deploy our codes to servers, I am not allowed to update/upgrade packages there... 
Other than this, any reason why it might be saying false?

Comment: `puts host.inspect` prints this: `[nil]`

Comment: So, it's not a nil and not empty array. Are you explicitly passing `nil` to the method?

Comment: No :( I am not passing anything at all... Check the update above, `host[0].nil?` prints true!! Got that idea from your last suggestion to inspect...

Comment: Since you're new to ruby, I think you're passing explicit nil without knowing it. Take snippet from my answer, put it exactly as it is to a separate ruby file (without anything else) and run it. If `.empty?` returns true, then go inspect your code.

Comment: OK, you are right... I was making a call to the function like so: `send("pkill", process_name, host[0])` :P    
my error

Comment: Also, `host.nil?` is still `false`, but `.empty?` gives true :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to make the host parameter optional? The intended use of `*host` is if you have a variable number of parameters. For example, you method could be called like `pkill('blah')`, or `pkill('blah', 'bloo')` or `pkill('blah', 'bloo', 'bar')`, etc.

If you are just trying to say that `host` isn't a required argument, you should give it a default value. For example, your method could become

```
def pkill(process_name, host=nil)  
     puts host.nil?
     puts host
end
```

Comment: That's what default value does.